# Android studio IDE shows unresolved references / ignores imports, while builds are fine

Tags: android, android-studio

Since couple of days I have problems with my android studio IDE, quite desperate at the moment. Various library imports are not recognized any more (some are, some not, junit e.g. isn´t), showing me unresolved reference error and autocompletion isn´t working as a consequence. But it´s only the IDE, gradle builds are fine.

[image]

Gradle files should be fine, the pic is from a new project where everything is set up properly. Same problem with old and new projects. I tried like everything already:

- Deleting .idea folder + .iml files and reimporting the project
- Invalidate Caches / Restart...
- Deleting .android/cache
- Deleting HOME/.gradle/caches
- Downloaded and installed new Android Studio (v3.2.1), opened old, started new projects
- Switched kotlin plugin versions, compilesdk versions, android gradle plugin versions, kotlin versions, gradle versions

I did couple of updates at the same time, Android Studio to 3.2.1, Kotlin plugin to 1.3.0, android gradle plugin to 3.2.1, installed newest sdk 28, switched from gradle 4.6 to 4.10.2. Shortly before, I had another weird behavior, where opened files didn´t show the real content but instead cryptic, binary symbols for nearly all the gradle or source files. Only deleting whole project folder and recloning it from git solved that one. I blame a hard reset while studio was running for that. As if anything android studio related on my machine is messed up. But even new installation of studio does not help

Comment: try using different paths and directory for studio new installation also do not use old settings

Comment: Did not work either

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally solved the problem by completely removing all android studio installations (using the included uninstall.exe), deleting HOME/.android and all HOME/.AndroidStudiox.x folders, then reinstalling android studio (not finding anything from previous installations anymore). Could then even reimport my settings, exported previously

Comment: Next time you shouldn't need to do that, instead just Invalidate Resources / Restart should work

Comment: Where exactly can this action be found?

Comment: I think it's under the file menu in Android studio, but you can always go the the help menu and type invalidate and it'll show you where

Comment: Cannot find anything like 'Invalidate Resources'. Are you talking about 'Invalidate Caches / Restart...' under the File menu?

Comment: Oh yes my bad, that's the one

Comment: I mentioned that in my list as not solving the problem